# How to create a dialog box like the one that appears when you hold an emoji within your mobile device's keyboard?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to know the first steps on how to approach a type of dialog like [the one's shown in this article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/article/32220611/diverse-thumbs-up-emojis-with-different-skin-tones-finally-here).

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Nothing really as I haven't had time, but  I've brainstormed on adding a Stack widget and align the "popup" where the user is holding the screen (using GestureDetector), and then follow drag events

Comment: Share your code